# check url for a specific piece of text

Tags: php, html, drupal

Lets say i capture the url as `$url  = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] or $_GET['q']`.

How can i check for the condition if the url contains a piece of text say "x"?

What regex would be required for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use preg_match with a variable value, make sure you use preg_quote to escape any special characters:

```
$look_for = "x";
if (preg_match( "/".preg_quote($look_for, "/")."/i" , $url) ) {
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the strpos() function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

This is one example from there:

```
$mystring = 'abc';
$findme   = 'a';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

// Note our use of ===.  Simply == would not work as expected
// because the position of 'a' was the 0th (first) character.
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the functions for finding the string, you may also want to check out Drupal's arg() function: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/arg/6

Comment: indeed, this was my first thought too

Answer (score 0):

I think [preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) would serve you well:

```
 if (preg_match( "/x/i" , $url) ) {


}
```

Comment: afaik, strpos performs quicker in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

If your working with a url from the wild you might want to use php's parse_url(), http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php , that will make it easy to work with. If it is a drupal URL your probably going to want to use Drupal's arg() function, http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/arg/6 , but it can have issues with the Pathauto module